# Solution to periodic potential GP equation

Tags: superfluidity, non-linear-schroedinger

Consider the boundary condition $\psi(0)=\psi(2\pi)$ and the Hamiltonian (and corresponding nonlinear Schrödinger equation):
$$\left[\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}-\Omega\right)^2+2\pi\gamma|\psi(\theta)|^2\right]\psi(\theta)=\mu\psi(\theta)$$

---

I read [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.4385.pdf) about this model, but when I try to re-do this result I failed. I think there might be something wrong in this paper, so I would like to ask if there is anyone willing to give a hand. Thanks!

Comment: The complete/detailed derivation of the set of solutions of this equation can found in [this article](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.62.063610).

Comment: @dolan thx, but I'm looking for a solution where the kinetic energy contains a nontrivial $\Omega$ term. If the Hamiltonian is written in what you suggested, the boundary condition would be $f(0)=f(1)e^{i\Omega}$, which is not the boundary condition it mentioned.